# PTU schunk PW70 drivers

Tags: ros, schunk

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

As my experience is limited within ROS, I would like to ask what is the best procedure to follow in order to connect the PTU Schunk PW70. The PTU is connected via serial-to-USB adapter but so far, my efforts with COB packages and ki-ros-pkg available online in "github.com/alesko/ki-ros-pkg/tree/master/amtec" were unsuccessful. So I would really appreciate if someone has any directions to follow.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58727/ptu-schunk-pw70-drivers/) by [kch](https://answers.ros.org/users/4483/kch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
You can look at [ros_canopen](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_canopen) and [schunk_robots](http://wiki.ros.org/schunk_robots)

---

Originally posted by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) with karma: 170 on 2015-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0